# Copying a local file by using native means of the filesystem

Tags: go, filesystems

Is there really no way to copy a local file by

- using some portable way
- using built in golang calls ...
- ... which in turn use the native API of the operating system ?

All ways I found make use of some kind of `Reader` / `Writer` or use buffers to copy the content of the source to the target, either bytewise or blockwise or - even worse - spawn commands like `cp`.

Even add on libraries like `[gut/yos][1]` that I found by searching [awesomego](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#file-handling) internally do [the same](https://github.com/1set/gut/blob/a8236323199758332aabe154b64a4e67a9d5c214/yos/copy.go#L111)

The downside of just reading the source file and writing the content to a new file is that you have to take care that these "properties" (depending on the OS you are using) of the source and destination match:

- timestamps
- permissions
- setuid bits
- (soft/hard) links
- alternate data streams

I know there are specialized libraries that for example expose the Windows API and enable one to call `CopyFileEx`. But this approach would be limited to Windows and I need at least to support Linux.

Comment: What's wrong with open both, read from input copy to output, close both?

Comment: @Volker Every other programming language I know (but perhaps I only use the wrong ones ...) provides a function that uses the underlying OS to copy files. When you read/write on your own you lose everything that the OS takes care of: timestamps, permissions, soft/hard links, specialized bits, ... and have to make sure you set them once the copy was made.

Comment: How can you use the underlying os to copy files ? There is no copy syscall on linux (to my knowledge). Maybe you can rely on something like `cp`, but it's not really the OS. To do so just `exec.Command("cp", "file1", "file2")`

Comment: "Every other programming language I know provides a function that uses the underlying OS to copy file". Can you provide some example ?

Comment: Can you give an example which function of the linux kernel (e.g.) provides the "copy file" function of the OS you are thinking of? Or Windows if you feel more comfortable there? Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: Python (https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) and Perl (https://metacpan.org/release/NWCLARK/perl-5.8.9/view/lib/File/Copy.pm), but Python documents (see first link) it is not able to copy all metadata

Comment: Neither the Python nor the Perl solution uses "native OS API" to copy files. Is this a XY problem? Or are you looking for "cp implemented in Go"? Note that asking for libraries is OT on SO.

Comment: @Volker I know, I've taken the tour. I will try to rephrase this question / ask a new question because the underlying problem is how to copy files without losing information. But as one can argue that this question is asking for libraries / offsite information it is probably better to ask / discuss this outside SO.

Comment: Note that the task you are after is at the border to impossible: You can mount two different filesystems which provide different metadata and copying from one to the other ultimately will loose some metadata.

Comment: @Volker Sure, whatever we do in golang can't be better than what the OS is able to do. And copying for example from NTFS to FAT will certainly lose data. But I'm in search of a solution where it is technically feasible (speaking: the involved filesystem allow to do so)  to retain metadata and alike and achieve this in golang.